# 2 botones en una misma línea flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Favor su ayuda!
Necesito situar un botón hacia el extremo derecho de este widget, hasta ahora no lo he logrado. El código es:

```
Widget _registerButtonContainer() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0),
      child: Material(  //Wrap with Material
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(22.0) ),
        elevation: 18.0,
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // Add This
        child: new MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          child: new Text(Texts.REGISTER,
              style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: _registerButtonAction,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Puedes agregar más info, o agregar la imagen de como se ve en tu pantalla y como quieres que quede para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Ya has intentado usar la clase [`Row`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)?

La clase `Row` tiene un atributo `children` que acepta una lista de Widgets: `Widget[]`, los `Widgets` dentro del la clase `Row` estarán alineados uno al otro. Debes tener cuidado por que si los `Widgets` son demasiado grandes, uno de ellos se desbordara de la pantalla. Para ello puedes usar la etiqueta `Expanded` y usar su atributo `flex` para asignarle un ancho. Por ejemplo, si tienes dos `Expanded` en un `Row` y a ambos le asignas `flex: 5` ambos tomaran la mitad del `Widget` padre.

#### Ejemplo

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Text('Deliver features faster', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Text('Craft beautiful UIs', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
        child: const FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Gracias!, el row debiera ir insertado como child del padding?, gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Si quieres que cada botón tenga la elevación de la clase ```Material```, entonces si, si no, como hijo de la clase ```Material```.

Comment: Lo solucioné con un buttonbar, gracias Alex!

Answer (score 0):

Hola si te sirve de algo, Yo lo solucione con un Widget llamado Flexible.

El Row widget quiere determinar el tamaño intrínseco de sus hijos no flexibles para saber cuánto espacio le queda para los flexibles. Sin embargo, TextField no tiene un ancho intrínseco; solo sabe cómo dimensionarse al ancho completo de su contenedor principal. Intente envolverlo en Flexible o Expanded para decirle Row que espera TextField que ocupe el espacio restante

```
    Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: widget.producto?.codigo ?? '',
              onChanged: ( value ) => codigo = value,
              decoration: CustomInputs.loginInputDecoration(
                hint: 'Codigo del Producto', 
                label: 'Producto', 
                icon: Icons.new_releases_outlined
              ),
              style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: widget.producto?.description ?? '',
              onChanged: ( value ) => description = value,
              decoration: CustomInputs.loginInputDecoration(
                hint: 'Descripción del Producto', 
                label: 'Descripción', 
                icon: Icons.new_releases_outlined
              ),
              style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Espero te funcione.
Saludos